# Connect telerik appbuilder to Azure documentdb

Tags: azure, telerik, azure-cosmosdb, telerik-appbuilder

We're using the appbuilder extension in Visual Studio. We're trying to find ways to connect to our azure document database. We want to know how we can connect to this database and add, say a name or just a number to it (for now).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik AppBuilder doesn't have integration w/ Azure DocumentDB *yet*.

If you're looking to to simple connect to a DocumentDB database to do some simple CRUD operations (e.g. add a name or number field) - I'd recommend checking out one of the following:

[The Document Explorer inside the Azure Portal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/documentdb/archive/2014/10/09/document-explorer-collection-management-and-new-metrics.aspx):

[image]

or [mingaliu's DocumentDB Studio](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases):

[image: DocumentDB Studio]